# C# Blazor Server: How to create Cookies serverside (in Web-API)

Tags: c#, cookies, blazor-server-side

I have a **Blazor Server** (aka Blazor Serverside) with some **Web-API** Controllers (.NET Core 3.1) and a **Blazor WebAssembly** (aka Blazor Clientside) project.

This is the **Web-API** (part of blazor server):

```
[ApiController]
public partial class UserApiController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("API/User/Login")]
    public IActionResult Login(string someParam)
    {
        // get cookie info
        var cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["userId"];

        // cookie settings
        CookieOptions cookieOptions = new CookieOptions();
        cookieOptions.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
        cookieOptions.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;

        // add/modify cookie
        string userId = "MyUserId";
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("userId", userId, cookieOptions);

        return Ok(userId);
    }
}
```

On **Blazor WebAssembly** (and on Blazor Server) I call something like this:

```
string someParam = "just testing...";
var apiResult = await Http.PostJsonAsync<string>("API/User/Login", someParam);

if(apiResult != null)
{
    // ...
}
```

I try to share the logic and components between the Blazor WebAssembly and the Blazor Server project, so on Blazor Server I use the same as above and I add the `HttpClient`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    if (!services.Any(service => service.ServiceType == typeof(HttpClient)))
    {
        services.AddScoped(service =>
        {
            // Get the base url (with navigation manager) and set as HttpClient base address
            var navigationManager = service.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
            return new HttpClient
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(navigationManager.BaseUri)
            };
        });
    }
}
```

This is the result:

Blazor WebAssembly

- Call to Web-API works
- Cookies working in Postman
- Cookies working in Chrome

Blazor Server

- Call to Web-API works
- Cookies working in Postman
- Cookies **NOT working** in Chrome

I tried different launches:

- http://localhost
- https://localhost
- http://MyPcName
- https://MyPcName

If I rerun the Api-Call on Blazor Server, I can read the value `var cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["userId"];`, but after Reload the value is gone (because Chrome didn't save any cookies).
I guess there is a different in the HttpClient call between my component and Postman for example, because Postman saved the cookie, but chrome did not.

Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... seems like the only way is via JavaScript?!